# how can I execute "java" command by java code?

Tags: java, ubuntu, command-line, agents-jade, multi-agent

I'm trying to run a multi-agent system using [JADE](https://jade.tilab.com/) by code.
Usually, I can run the jade system by command line using the following command:

```
java jade.Boot -gui
```

It also works well using Netbeans IDE by changing the project properties and pointing the run configuration to the jade.Boot class.

My problem is: I want to run this system by java code... let's say, when a user clicks a button, and as far as I know, this command specified above should work using the following code:

```
Process p=null;                                                                                                                                                     
try {
    p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java jade.Boot -gui;");
} 
catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(SimulationCreator.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
            
BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
String s;
try {
    while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
           System.out.println(s);
    }
} catch (IOException ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(SimulationCreator.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

But I'm getting nothing, neither the JADE system is running nor I'm getting any error.

What am I missing ?

P.S.: I'm working on ubuntu 20.0.

P.S.: running other commands by code like "ps -aux" works very well!

Comment: Try reading and printing the error stream to see if there are errors.  Is the classpath set to the folder holding the jade folder?

Comment: @NormR yes it appears to be a problem related to the class path, thank you ! now I'm working on solving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem may be a difference between PATH of the current running VM, compared the shell (bash etc) you use and implicit passing of CLASSPATH. Check the location of java which `which java` in the shell that works and try using in your `exec`.

Also you won't see all issues when running as you don't access the error stream at same time as the output stream, changing to ProcessBuilder allows easier debugging as you can redirect the out/err streams to a file. But if JADE runs for a long time or produces a lot of output you should consumer STDOUT+ERR in background threads.

Try this in jshell:

```
String[] cmd = new String[]{"java", "jade.Boot", "-gui"};
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmd); 
File fileOut = new File("stdout.log"); 
File fileErr = new File("stderr.log"); 
pb.redirectError(fileErr); 
pb.redirectOutput(fileOut); 
Process p = pb.start(); 
int rc = p.waitFor();
String stdout = Files.readString(fileOut.toPath());
String stderr = Files.readString(fileErr.toPath());

System.out.println("Exit   : "+rc +' '+(rc == 0 ? "OK":"**** ERROR ****"));
System.out.println("STDOUT : "+stdout);
System.out.println("STDERR : "+stderr);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, it worked well on jshell but it is giving "ClassNotFoundException" with code, how can I fix the classpath problem ? as for "which java" it gave the same output "/usr/bin/java" @DuncG

Comment: Your command line shell call that works probably picks up jade using the environment variable CLASSPATH. Try `echo $CLASSPATH`, and maybe you can add "-cp" and that value to your launch from ProcessBuilder(cmd), or pass the value into your java app launch as `-Dmyjade.classpath=whatever` and refer to `System.getProperty("myjade.classpath")`  after "-cp". Alternatively if your shell has everything setup already you might be able to launch the shell passing in the jade command such as `cmd = {"bash", "-c", "java jade.Boot -gui"}